# How can I speed up WebDAV?

Tags: configuration, webdav

I have successfully configured and connected to my Tridion WebDAV instance but it is mind-numbingly slow, even when browsing the file structure.

Is there any way I can speed this up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE contains a feature which attempts to “Automatically detect settings” by making use of the WPAD protocol to discover a web proxy. This is achieved in the following ways:

1. As part of the DHCP configuration received by the host (or)
2. By performing DNS request(s).

The Web Client Service (responsible for WebDAV browsing) will perform auto-discovery more frequently when none of them succeed, and therefore making Webdav usage very slow.

**Complete the following (on the client machine) to resolve the slow performance:**

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to the Menu “Tools” > “Internet Options” then go to the tab “Connections”
   Click on button “LAN Settings”
3. Uncheck the box “Automatically detect settings”
4. Close and restart all running Internet Explorer processes
5. Restart the “Web Client” Service

More information can be found here : http://www.marc-lognoul.me/itblog-en/using-a-webdav-folder-maybe-very-slow-on-windows-vista-or-windows-seven/